# Why are my messages from BehivourSubject duplicated every new recieved message?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using BehivourSubject for recieve data, also using websocket but websocket is not important for now. For now is very important why I always got duplicated message from BehivourSubject.

Check code in service:

```
hubMessage$ = new BehaviorSubject({});  


public startConnection = (id: number) => { 
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://api/hub')
        .build();


    this.hubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => { 
            console.log('connection established')
        }
        )
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err)
            this.retryConnection();
        }) 
}

public newLocationRecieved() {
    this.hubConnection.on('NewLoc', (data) => { 
        console.log('new location recieved' , data)
        this.hubMessage$.next(data); 
    })
}

public sendDriverId(id: number = 1) {
    this.hubConnection.send('SubOnDriver', { driverId: id })
}
```

Every 20 seconds i got new location. I need to remove previous data from this hubMessage or what ever but my software crash after one minute because duplicated message.

Imagine that your messages are duplicated. To get one first, then two, then four, then sixty..32....64..

Why?

How to solve this ?

I am using this message in component:

Component code:

```
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.dispatchDetails;
    this.createMarkers();
  }

  createMarkers() {
    console.log('Connection start right now ', this.dispatchDetails) 
    this.newCoordinate(); 
  }


  private newCoordinate = () => { 
      this.signalRService.hubMessage$.subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          console.log('recieved new coordinate ?', data); // HERE I GOT SO MUCH DUPLICATED MESSAGE
          this.signalRService.newLocationRecieved()
          this.locationCoords = data;
          if (this.locationCoords.location) {
            this.latitude = this.locationCoords?.location?.latitude
            this.longitude = this.locationCoords?.location?.longitude
          }
        }
      )
    }
```

I probably need to clear my variable...
Or maybe is problem with websocket connection ?

is the websocket connection duplicated? Which I don't believe

you probably know that I can't make minimal reproduction code because these are web sockets ...

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are calling `createMarkers()` function from `ngOnChanges` life cycle. `ngOnChanges` will be called again and again when there is component scoped value change. So, new subscriptions will be created again and again, so you have bunch of duplicated messages. You need to call that function only when you create a component or whatever only one time. Or you need to kill existing subscription first before creating a new subscription.

Comment: Ok i am set to onInit but again duplicate message.

Answer (score 2):

You've subscribed to `this.signalRService.hubMessage$` and on any new data you receive from that behavior subject you call `this.signalRService.newLocationRecieved()`

```js
this.signalRService.hubMessage$.subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      ...
      this.signalRService.newLocationRecieved()
    }
```

which in turn creates a brand new callback

```
public newLocationRecieved() {
    this.hubConnection.on('NewLoc', (data) => { 
        this.hubMessage$.next(data); 
    })
}
```

hence your duplicated values. What I would suggest is moving the callback into the `startConnection` function

```js
public startConnection = (id: number) => {
  ...
  this.hubConnection.on('NewLoc', (data) => {
    console.log('new location recieved', data)
    this.hubMessage$.next(data);
  });
}
```

Edit:

Also `this.createMarkers();` should be moved out of `ngOnChanges` into `ngOnInit`. All credit to @Liu Zhang

Answer (score -1):

In the message handler inside `newCoordinate`, you call `this.signalRService.newLocationRecieved()` , which sets up another event handler that publishes another message into the same `hubMessage$`. You want to do this only once, probably in `startConnection`.